# Windows Forms Accept Button is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on my homework which is a calculator in windows form and I am facing the problem that I have set the form accept button is equal button but by pressing the enter, backspace button is working and backspace button has background image and when I run my app then backspace button is highlighted or focused. Why its happening?

Comment: We cannot possibly begin to answer without any code.

Comment: dear but this problem is related to windows form design or button properties.

Comment: @Bili - this problem is related to your code which you haven't shown us.  it's highly unlikely that you've discovered a lingering bug in winforms.

Comment: so you mean there is something wrong with the taborder of your controls or with the events when you press the buttons?

Comment: Backspace button is highlighted when I start my app I want to ask why backspace is highlighted and when I press enter backspace button is pressed.

Comment: @Bili does `highlighted` mean `Focused` ? Have you tried to use `Focus()` method?

Comment: Yes it means focused. No I did not try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 this.KeyPreview = true;
```

needs to be after initializeComponent

Infact nothing should be in front of this except for special reasons.
I am sure there is more wrong here, but start with this, then we will move on

try

```
equalButton.Focus()
```

Right after the initialComponent()

But if you have a control highlighted and you press enter it will select that button.  Go file print on your web browser, use your keys and tab to highlight cancel and press enter. Cancel will be selected.

The accept button is only meant to be used when inside a textbox, that has

```
AcceptReturn=false;
```

Or I believe if you have no controls highlighted.  What you will need to do is go into each of your control keypreview event, and fire your equal button when

```
if (e.keycode == keys.Enter)
    equalsButton_Click(new object(), EventArgs.empty)
```

**Edit**  what I would do is add to each of your button onfocus events, they can all point to this method

```
public button1_onfocus(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    myTextbox.focus();
}
```

this way yoru textbox will always be the focus, and if they hit return, your textbox has the focus so it will fire your acceptbutton.

non of my code samples have been tested for syntax accuracy

Comment: Can I chat with you on stackoverflow? Stackoverflow allow us to chat?

Comment: Sorry for the late response I can't do chat, ISP blocks it.